# Reimplimenting a DLL method variable with C++ in visual studio at ABI level

Tags: class, visual-c++, dll, static

I have a third party DLL in C++ that I'd like to replace with one I've made myself...
This is a clean room type exercise just for learning purposes ; and I am hoping to make a replacement DLL that can be used with programs linked against the original DLL -- without recompiling the applications.

I am using the same visual studio compiler version (9) used to make the original DLL, but I do not have the original source code for the DLL.

The DLL consists of a C++ class, and some extern "C" functions to handle constructor/destructors, so that all memory management is isolated to the DLL.

I used dependency walker to inspect the original DLL, and demangle/undecorate the linker symbols -- and have attempted to write prototypes for the class and methods ; and then I wrote a python script to take the object code compiled from my class -- and make a .def file that chooses the closest mangled symbols from MY obj code compared against the original DLL exports;  ( Allows some qualifier variations, but not name variations ) and then I build a DLL from my obj code using that .def file to have an identical ABI ordering in the DLL.

I am at the stage where dependency walker can not tell the difference between my DLL and the original when it comes to listing the types -- although *there are small differences in several of the mangled names* that I would like to resolve...

One member is very troublesome to figure out as it is not a function, but supposedly member data eg: a decorated ?pzSambaAddress@HWInterface@@2PBDB shows up as:

```
char const * const HWInterface::pzSambaAddress ; // in dependency walker
```

And I'm not sure if dependency walker is decoding the mangling wrong or not, because
I can't figure out how to implement anything even remotely like this in my header file which would export a symbol to an .obj file, let alone to a DLL.

What kinds of definitions could create something like that?

If I type it in (as shown above) to my header file, it's a constant string -- therefore I'm thinking it has to be initialized in the constructor methods, something like this:

```
HWInterface::HWInterface(HWInterface const & iface) : pzSambaAddress("dummy") {
    std :: cout << this -> pzSambaAddress; // access it, to force compiler
}
```

But when I compile that, pzSambaAddress, does not show up in the obj file at all.
Obviously because it's not an allocated memory location prior to class instantiation.

eg: dumpbin /SYMBOLS HWInterface.obj | grep "pzSam" finds nothing.

I could add the static keyword to the definition of pzSambaAddress and initialize it exactly once for the whole class.

```
char const * const HWInterface::pzSambaAddress="a samba name constant.";
```

The name then mangles to: ?pzSambaAddress@HWInterface@@2QBDB

But dependency walker doesn't say it's static... Nor is mangled @@2QBDB quite @@2PBDB... and that will also mean that I can also no longer initialize individual instances with constructors.

HWInterface.cpp(25) : error C2438: 'pzSambaAddress' : cannot initialize static class data via constructor

So Q1:  Is a static constant the cause of the exported symbol, and dependency walker just doesn't say "static" -- or are there other ways it could be generated / initialized ?

Secondly:

Is there anything better at demangling, and giving information on esoteric qualifiers?

When I run dumpbin on an object file, I get all kinds of qualifiers that dependency walker doesn't show (on other symbols, not the example we've been talking about).
 dumpbin.exe /symbols myOwnFile.obj

But as I don't have the obj file for the original DLL, nor the .lib, that switch doesn't work.  Running dumpbin.exe /symbols on the DLL gives me nothing.
Running dumpbin.exe /exports on the DLL merely gives me the mangled names.
There is also a VC++ console application "undname.exe", but often it doesn't undecorate the name passed on the command line at all, but gives most of the name back still mangled.

I looked around a lot on the web, but am finding only partially accurate/incomplete information, which wasn't enough to solve the problem I just showed.

[Wikipedia on mangling names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C++_name_mangling)

Any ideas of where to find a more verbose/accurate demangler program for visual C++ ?

Answer (score 1):

```
class HWInterface {
    public:
    __declspec(dllexport) 
    static char const *  pzSambaAddress;
};

char const*  HWInterface::pzSambaAddress = "hello";
```

Then:

```
C:\temp>cl /LD test.cpp
...

C:\temp>dumpbin /exports test.dll
...
Dump of file test.dll
...    
    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 00008000 ?pzSambaAddress@HWInterface@@2PBDB
```

You can use the `undname` utility included with MSVC to decode mangled names:

```
C:\temp>undname ?pzSambaAddress@HWInterface@@2PBDB
Microsoft (R) C++ Name Undecorator
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Undecoration of :- "?pzSambaAddress@HWInterface@@2PBDB"
is :- "public: static char const * const HWInterface::pzSambaAddress"
```

However, you'll note that `undname` says that there should be an extra `const` in there. As you saw, adding that extra `const` gets you a slightly different mangled name (with a 'Q' instead of a 'P' near the end:

Using `static char const * const` instead of `static char const *` produces `?pzSambaAddress@HWInterface@@2QBDB`

`undname` imports a function from the C runtime, `_unDNameEx`, that I assume is used to demangle names (and I assume that Dependency Walker uses it, too - apparently via an interface in DBGHELP.DLL). Looks like there's a bug in the demangler.

The GNU tools have a similar utility, `c++filt`, to decode g++ mangled names.

Comment: Yes, I can see clearly there is a bug in some of the un-decorate libraries that are available with Visual studio; what version are you using?  The best version I have of undname.exe is md5sum : ff8f053c9a896be915b4cb9b5f6feb3e , and it does not always correctly un-name items;  For example:  undname ?bIsBluetoothAddress@HWInterface@@UAE_NABV?@DV?@DV?@D@ATL@@@@@ATL@@@Z will return ?bIsBluetoothAddress@HWInterface@@UAE_NABV?@DV?@DV?@D@ATL@@@@@ATL@@@Z with absolutely no un-decoration of the name.

Comment: I think I located the problem; There are different versions of msvcrt.dll that can run on my system; and it's likely using an older version.

Comment: Nope...  I explicitly linked to msvcrt.dll version  7.0.7601.17744 md5:9dc80a8aaaaac397bdab3c67165a824, and it has exactly the same problem.  Dependency walker, strangely enough, does better than an exe directly linked against dll version 7. And when I run dependency walker on itself (latest version), it doesn't show itself being linked to the DBGHELP.DLL or to msvcrt.dll.  So, I think the newer dependency walker might not use microsoft's library.  It reports: bool HWInterface::bIsBluetoothAddress(class ATL::CStringT<char,class StrTraitMFC_DLL<char,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<char> > > const &)